# Java class PdfFormFiller after compilation error

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I have a problem with compiling this java project https://github.com/nkitsul/pdfformfiller2

```
mkdir PdfFormFiller
cd PdfFormFiller/
git clone https://github.com/nkitsul/pdfformfiller2.git .
cd lib/
wget https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/releases/download/5.5.0/itext-5.5.0.zip
unzip itext-5.5.0.zip 
cd ..
mkdir bin
javac -cp lib/itextpdf-5.5.0.jar PdfFormFiller.java -d bin/
java -cp ./bin PdfFormFiller.PdfFormFiller
```

After that I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/DocumentException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
My OS - Debian wheezy java version "1.7.0_55" OpenJDK Runtime

Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1~deb7u1) OpenJDK 64-Bit

Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode) 

javac 1.7.0_55
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `iText` JAR file to the runtime classpath

```
java -cp ./bin:lib/itextpdf-5.5.0.jar PdfFormFiller.PdfFormFiller
```

Comment: Upvoting is also a way to say thanks. (There's now a 1 next to the answer.)